Is $n>6$ perfect if $\vert\sum_{d\mid n}(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2})^{d}-K\vert\lt\frac{1}{2n}$?
Let $K:=\sum_{k\ge 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\right)^{2^{k}}$. The observation that the sequence of divisors of a large enough (even) perfect number is "close" to a sequence of consecutive powers of $2$ makes me ask this question:
Is $n>6$ perfect if $\vert K-\sum_{d\mid 
 n}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\right)^{d}\vert\lt\frac{1}{2n}$?
Edit after anomaly's comment below:
My condition may be necessary but is not sufficient. One may thus further require that $n$ is not a power of $2$ and that $\frac{d_{+}(n)}{d_{-}(n)}-\frac{1}{2n}\gt\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ where $d_{+}(n)$ is the least divisor of $n$ greater than $\sqrt{n}$ and $d_{-}(n)$ the greatest divisor of $n$ less than $\sqrt{n}$.

A computation shows that the statement fails for many values of $n$, starting at $n = 8$. (It also looks like it fails for every power of $2$, though $n = 88$ is the first other value for which it fails.)
